# update xsl file with xmlstaret, grep or similar

Tags: xslt, grep, xmlstarlet

I have a series of similar XSL files and to all of them, I have to add the same XSL element in a specific position.

Here you can find a portion of the XSL to be updated and the element to be inserted is
`<xsl:call-template name="distributor.xsl"/>`
and it has to be after the `</mrd:distributionFormat>` and before the `<mrd:transferOptions>` tags

Is there a way to automatize this update to all my XSL files using XmlStarlet grep or similar?

```
...
<mdb:distributionInfo>
      <mrd:MD_Distribution>
         <mrd:distributionFormat>
            <mrd:MD_Format>
               <mrd:formatSpecificationCitation>
                  <cit:CI_Citation>
                     <cit:title>
                        <gco:CharacterString>WCS</gco:CharacterString>
                     </cit:title>
                     <cit:date gco:nilReason="unknown"/>
                     <cit:edition>
                        <gco:CharacterString>2.0</gco:CharacterString>
                     </cit:edition>
                  </cit:CI_Citation>
               </mrd:formatSpecificationCitation>
            </mrd:MD_Format>
         </mrd:distributionFormat>
                 <!-- call-template  -->           
                <xsl:call-template name="distributor.xsl"/>
                 <!-- call-template -->
         <mrd:transferOptions>
         ...
```

I tried with

`xmlstarlet ed -P -S -L -s //mrd:MD_Distribution -t elem -i xsl:include -t attr -n "name" -v "distributor.xsl" main.xsl`
where main.xsl is the file to be updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*After changed requirements*

Following commmand inserts the desired `xsl:call-template` node where
you want (for details see my first posting),

```sh
xmlstarlet edit \
    -i '//mrd:transferOptions[1]' \
    -t elem -n 'xsl:call-template' -v '' \
    -s '$prev' -t attr -n name -v 'distributor.xsl' \
main.xsl
```

when run on the following XML file (adjust namespaces as needed):

```xsl
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:cit="urn:so70244776_cit"
  xmlns:gco="urn:so70244776_gco"
  xmlns:mdb="urn:so70244776_mdb"
  xmlns:mrd="urn:so70244776_mrd"
>
  <xsl:template name="x">
    <mdb:distributionInfo>
        <mrd:MD_Distribution>
           <mrd:distributionFormat>
              <mrd:MD_Format>
                 <mrd:formatSpecificationCitation>
                    <cit:CI_Citation>
                       <cit:title>
                          <gco:CharacterString>WCS</gco:CharacterString>
                       </cit:title>
                       <cit:date gco:nilReason="unknown"/>
                       <cit:edition>
                          <gco:CharacterString>2.0</gco:CharacterString>
                       </cit:edition>
                    </cit:CI_Citation>
                 </mrd:formatSpecificationCitation>
              </mrd:MD_Format>
           </mrd:distributionFormat>
           <mrd:transferOptions/>
        </mrd:MD_Distribution>
    </mdb:distributionInfo>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 1):

In a POSIX shell the following [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) command:

```sh
xmlstarlet edit \
    -N xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" \
    -N mdb="urn:so70244776_mdb" \
    -N mrd="urn:so70244776_mrd" \
    --var templatename "'distributor-N.xsl'" \
    --var anchornode '//mrd:distributionFormat[1]' \
    -d '$anchornode/following-sibling::xsl:call-template' \
    -a '$anchornode' -t elem -n 'xsl:call-template' -v '' \
    -a '$xstar:prev' -t attr -n name -v '' \
    -u '$xstar:prev' -x '$templatename' \
main.xsl
```

- declares a number of namespace bindings
- selects `//mrd:distributionFormat[1]` as anchor node
- deletes any existing `xsl:call-template` sibling nodes following the anchor
- appends a new `xsl:call-template` element with a `name` attribute

`xmlstarlet edit` code can use the convenience `$xstar:prev` (aka
`$prev`) node to refer to the node created by the most recent
`-i` / `--insert`, `-a` / `--append`, or `-s` / `--subnode` option.
Examples of `$xstar:prev` are given in
[doc/xmlstarlet.txt](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/xmlstarlet.txt)
and the source code's examples/ed-backref*.
In the command shown its first use refers to the `xsl:call-template`
element, the second to the `name` attribute.

**EDIT**: It turns out `xmlstarlet edit` isn't as picky as I thought
it was so an alternative, shorter command would be (attribute nodes
can be added with `-s`, `-i`, or `-a`):

```sh
xmlstarlet edit \
    --var anchor '//mrd:distributionFormat[1]' \
    -d '$anchor/following-sibling::xsl:call-template' \
    -a '$anchor' -t elem -n 'xsl:call-template' -v '' \
    -s '$prev' -t attr -n name -v 'distributor-N.xsl' \
main.xsl
```

---

Given the following (demo) input:

```xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:mdb="urn:so70244776_mdb"
  xmlns:mrd="urn:so70244776_mrd"
>
   <xsl:template name="q">
      <mdb:distributionInfo>
         <mrd:MD_Distribution>
            <mrd:distributionFormat>
               <mrd:MD_Format>
                  <mrd:formatSpecificationCitation/>
               </mrd:MD_Format>
            </mrd:distributionFormat>
            <xsl:call-template name="distributor.xsl"/>
            <!-- x -->
            <xsl:call-template name="distributor-1.xsl"/>
            <mrd:transferOptions/>
         </mrd:MD_Distribution>
      </mdb:distributionInfo>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

either command above produces the following output:

```xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:mdb="urn:so70244776_mdb" xmlns:mrd="urn:so70244776_mrd" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template name="q">
    <mdb:distributionInfo>
      <mrd:MD_Distribution>
        <mrd:distributionFormat>
          <mrd:MD_Format>
            <mrd:formatSpecificationCitation/>
          </mrd:MD_Format>
        </mrd:distributionFormat>
        <xsl:call-template name="distributor-N.xsl"/>
        <!-- x -->
        <mrd:transferOptions/>
      </mrd:MD_Distribution>
    </mdb:distributionInfo>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```